# Deploy ASP.NET Core on Server with Github Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, github-actions, windows-server

I'm using github actions to deploy my projects on my windows server using FTP

name: .NET

on:
push:
branches: [ main ]
pull_request:
branches: [ main ]

jobs:
build:

```
runs-on: windows-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Setup .NET
  uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
  with:
    dotnet-version: 6.0.x
- name: Init Utilities
  run: git submodule update --init
- name: Get Utilities
  run: git submodule update --remote -f
- name: Restore dependencies
  run: dotnet restore
- name: Build
  run: dotnet build --no-restore
- name: Publish
  run: dotnet publish
- name: Deploy
  uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
  with:
    local-dir: LOCAL_DIR
    server: SERVER
    username: USERNAME
    password: PASSWORD
    dangerous-clean-slate: true
```

the problem is that I have to manually stop the server so the files could be uploaded.

but I don't want to stop the server manually. is there any way so I can force update the project without stoping the server or stop the server automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `app_offline.htm` to make your site offline. When publishing is complete, delete the app_offline.htm file.

Official doc: [Taking Web Applications Offline with Web Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/taking-web-applications-offline-with-web-deploy)

You can [refer the link to add `app_offline.htm` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65137920/7687666) when you delpoy the app.